# How to print the entries made in my LinkedList?

Tags: java, linked-list, java.util.scanner

I need help concerning my coursework in Java Programming. I am creating a console Flower (shop) application which stores the flower's name, colour, age and price. However, I am having problems printing the LinkedList I created to store records of the Flowers added. I have tried tweaking with the showFlowers method in the Test class for a while now and nothing is working. I'd appreciate the help, thanks. Here's my code.

Flower Class

```
public class Flower {
    //variables
    private String name; //name of flower
    private String colour; //colour of flower
    private int age; //age of flower (days)
    private double price; //price of flower

    public Flower(String n, String c, int a, double p) {
        this.name = n;
        this.colour = c;
        this.age = a;
        this.price = p;
    }

    public void getName() {
        System.out.println("Name: " + this.name);
    }

    public void getColour() {
        System.out.println("Colour: " + this.colour);
    }

    public void getAge() {
        System.out.println("Age (Days): " + this.age);
    }

    public void getPrice() {
        System.out.println("Price: " + this.price);
    }

    public void getFullDetails(){
        System.out.println("Name: " + this.name);
        System.out.println("Colour: " + this.colour);
        System.out.println("Age (Days): " + this.age);
        System.out.println("Price: " + this.price);
    }
}
```

FlowerTest Class

```
package flower;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FlowerTest {

    private static LinkedList<Flower> myFlowers = new LinkedList();

    public static void firstMenu() {
        System.out.println("<------------ Welcome to the Flower Menu -------------->");
        System.out.println("1. Add Flower Details");
        System.out.println("2. Show All Flowers");
        System.out.println("3. Exit");
        System.out.println("Enter choice: ");
    }

    public static void mainMenu() {

        for (;;) {
            firstMenu();
            Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int choice = inputScanner.nextInt();

            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    createFlower(inputScanner);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    showFlowers(inputScanner);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Goodbye");
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;

                default:
                    //error handling
                    System.err.println("Unrecognized option");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static Flower createFlower(Scanner in) {
        System.out.println("<-------- Adding Flower ---------->");
        System.out.println("Input Flower Name: ");
        String name = in.next();
        System.out.println("Input Flower Colour: ");
        String colour = in.next();
        System.out.println("Input Flower Age (Days): ");
        int age = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input Flower Price: ");
        double price = in.nextDouble();
        return new Flower(name, colour, age, price);
    }

    public static void showFlowers(Scanner in){
                    for (Flower flower : myFlowers) {
                        flower.getFullDetails();
                    }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mainMenu();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note Your `getter` classes should not be printing the value but `returning` the value.

Comment: Define "not working". What is it doing, and how does that differ from what you expect it to do?

Comment: Also `for (;;)` is a big no-no. For one, it is semantically equivalent to `while(true)`, so you could just use that. But then, you should also not be using `while(true)` either, as you are then putting faith that the inner loop will fully control when the loop will stop with a call to `break` (which, incidentally, you never do, so the only way the program terminates is with your call to `System.exit(0)`, which is another coding snafu).

Comment: @Abion47, thank you for the advice. I wanted it to keep running currently until the user specifically exits at the basic level. Now that the adding bit of the LinkedList is working, I will focus more towards finetuning the way the application works and other error handlings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
createFlower(inputScanner)
```

to:

```
myFlowers.add(createFlower(inputScanner));
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears like your code is never adding any flowers to your `myFlowers` List.  Your `createFlower()` method simply returns the newly-created `Flower` object, but the return value is never used in your switch statement.

You should either make the `createFlower()` method `void` and have it add the flower to your List directly, or let it return the flower, and have the handling code in the switch statement add it to the List.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I needed to tweak the switch case 1 so it can add the flowers created to the myFlowers List directly as you said. Luckily, Mr. Steve led me in the right direction. I appreciate it.